# YourKit not showing complete information

Tags: java, profiling, weblogic, yourkit

My application is running on weblogic and creates multiple threads to process the request from client. While doing CPU profiling using YourKit, I observed that the information is not complete. The time shown in the YourKit is not matching with the one observed using application logs. Can someone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

YourKit Profiler measures wall time and CPU time for different methods (all is configurable). Invocation CPU time (real time on processor) might be different from wall time between method enter and exit you see in logs. See details at http://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/times.jsp

Best regards,
Vladimir Kondratyev
YourKit, LLC